# Почему на компьютере всё работает корекктно, а на андроид нет?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я столкнулся с проблемой, которую тяжело описать. У меня есть 2D проект в Unity. На компьютере всё работает нормально, как я и прописывал, а на андроиде всё идёт по другом. Не знаю как назвать эту проблему. Постараюсь описать проблемы на двух кадрах: есть один кадр, далее вместо него приходит второй кадр, но первый кадр никуда не пропадает, поэтому второй кадр будто накладывается на первый? Лучше посмотрите скриншот и узнайте - как обычный цикл по увеличению цифры выглядит на пк и как выглядит на андроид:

Пк:

[image: пк]

Андроид:
[image: Андроид]

Происходит это на всех сценах. На каждой сцене находится одинаковая камера. Вот её скриншот в изображении:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также укажу пакеты, которые добавлены в юнити:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По мимо камеры также есть и `[Debug Updater]`, но не думаю, что дело в нём. Сам я с этой проблемой не справлюсь, так как не знаю, что это такое. Даже не загуглить

Comment: Какой из скринов какой, что из этого нормально? О какой именно анимации кадров речь?

Comment: @aepot он же сказал - на ПК всё нормально. Значит первый скрин правильный. Ещё, как я понимаю у него идёт следующий кадр, а другой не удаляется

Comment: @aepot Сделал более подробнее

Comment: это может зависеть от версии Opengles30 которая установлена не телефоне, попробуй новые телефоны с андроид 11

Comment: @FatherOfFiveChildren Спасибо! Это оказалось правдой. Однако что же делать с устройствами ,где Opengeles30 старее? (Также оставьте ответ)